# pthread_t declarations need to be global?

Tags: pthreads, mingw-w64

[Edited and added reprex] When I put the declarations below in the beginning of the main() function, the behavior of the threads is erratic and incorrect.  When I make these declarations global, or not the first declarations in main(), everything works fine.  I'm using mingw-w64 on Windows 10.

`pthread_t  thr1, thr2, thr3;`

Below is the program, it spawns three threads to read integers from three different text files and add them all to a single global variable.  The call to pthread_join() for thr3 always fails with error code 3, and the final result of sum is different in different runs.  But it all works fine if the pthread_t declarations are in a different location.  I hope this is short enough it's less than 70 lines including whitespace.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

long sum = 0;

pthread_mutex_t  sumLock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* thrFunc(void* arg)
{
  char   curLine[50];
  FILE  *inFile = fopen((char*)arg, "r");
  long   curNum;

  if (!inFile) {
    printf("Error opening input file %s\n", arg);
    pthread_exit((void*)1);
  }

  while (fgets(curLine, sizeof(curLine), inFile)) {
    curNum = strtol(curLine, 0, 0);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&sumLock);
    sum += curNum;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&sumLock);
  }

  fclose(inFile);
  pthread_exit((void*)0);
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t  thr1, thr2, thr3;
  long       threadResult;
  int        err;

  if (pthread_create(&thr1, 0, thrFunc, (void*)"C:\\Users\\paulc\\long1.txt")) {
    printf("Failed to create thread thr1\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (pthread_create(&thr2, 0, thrFunc, (void*)"C:\\Users\\paulc\\long2.txt")) {
    printf("Failed to create thread thr2\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (pthread_create(&thr3, 0, thrFunc, (void*)"C:\\Users\\paulc\\long3.txt")) {
    printf("Failed to create thread thr3\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (err = pthread_join(thr1, (void**)&threadResult)) {
    printf("failed to join thr1, error code = %d\n", err);
  }

  if (err = pthread_join(thr2, (void**)&threadResult)) {
    printf("failed to join thr2, error code = %d\n", err);
  }

  if (err = pthread_join(thr3, (void**)&threadResult)) {
    printf("failed to join thr3, error code = %d\n", err);
  }

  printf("Total: %ld\n", sum);

}
```

Comment: Nope, they don't need to be global. The difference between declaring them in `main` versus declaring them as globals is that the global variables will be initialized to zero. That shouldn't matter if you're using them correctly. See [mcve].

Comment: We might have some insight into the true nature of the problem if you presented a [mre] demonstrating it.

Comment: Ok thanks I've added a reprex

Comment: My guess is that a pointer is 64 bits, and a `long` is 32 bits on your system. If that's true, then the `pthread_join` calls are the problem. By storing a pointer value (64 bits) into `thread_result` (32 bits), you end up overwriting `thr3`.

Comment: user3386109 you're right thanks